# IFileOpenDialog failed to launch in XP

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a sample application in which I want to selecting  a folder. For that I used SHBrowseForFolder(). But in Vista it will not work. So I used IFileOpenDialog. If the os version is XP I am using SHBrowseForFolder() else I am using IFileOpenDialog.

My application works fine in vista. But it will fail to launch in XP.

Please let me know any thing I need to do.

**Update:**

I observed that it is not because of IFileOpenDialog interface.
I am using SHCreateItemFromParsingName() API to set the Default Folder while browsing.
Shell32.dll does not contain entry point in XP. So I am facing this problem.

To solve the problem I am using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddres() to Get the Proc Address.

Now I can run the application.

Comment: Are you initializing COM before calling SHBrowseForFolder? As usual actually posting some code would greatly increase your chances of getting relevant and helpful answers.

Comment: "In Vista it will not work", what exactly does that mean? SHBrowseFolder works fine on Vista for me, what is the value of GetLastError()?

Answer (score 2):

Our product uses SHBrowserForFolder without issue on Vista/7.  What code do you have for that function?  What does GetLastError() return?  Maybe we can find the issue there.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, answering the direct question, IFileOpenDialog is not available in XP which is why it failed. The equivalent API for XP is GetOpenFileName.